# Webpack with svger causing huge bundle size

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, bundler

I am importing some svg and png files with webpack 5 in a react project.  I got some advice to use the [@svgr/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) package to process svg files.  It works, and its nice because it inlines the svg code instead of using an `<img src="path-to-file.svg" />` method.  Though this is not crucial.

My webpack rule is like this:

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack", "url-loader"],
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I import and use the svgs like this:

```
import LoadingSpinner from "./loading-spinner.svg";

const Thing = () => {
  return <img src={LoadingSpinner} />
}
```

Works like a charm.  Except that my bundle size is huge.  I'm importing about 15 or 20 files.  Each file is between 20 and 500 kb total.  Not tiny but not that big.  When I run my build, and analyze it with [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer), it shows me that my assets are being included in bundle.js, and that section of the code is huge:

[image]

bundle.js in this instance is 15 Mb.  Obviously I have some work to do as far as shrinking how all the node_modules are packaged.  But this question is about svger.

When I change my webpack config to use svgs as an asset, they are no longer bundled as part of bundle.js, and my bundle size shrinks by the 4+ Mb, as expected.  The config for that would be like this:

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

In this case, my bundle size shrinks, but I run into other problems.

Why does svger bundle the image files as part of bundlejs?  Is there a way to avoid this, and have it load as an external asset, while still maintaining the advantages of svger?

Comment: Did you find any solution related to this?

Comment: @ChetanKondawle no I ended up ditching svger and using `<img src="mysvg.svg" />` type syntax